# reactjs setstate not working in function that has .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, setstate

Good Morning.

Need help, i have the below script, the thing is the setState is not working, I think I'm missing something here? or Am i doing wrong. the "return" in the below is inside ".map" so i could display the 3 file in the array. Thanks

```
  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {

  // fileName: ['SAMPLE DOCUMENT 1', 'SAMPLE DOCUMENT 2', 'SAMPLE DOCUMENT 3'],
  file: [
    {fileName: 'SAMPLE DOCUMENT 1', id: 123456, hash: '9153BB2EFC17BF53218FA15C977EDCD3', fileStatus: 
'PENDING APPROVAL', fileId: 'APFEX-9153BB2E-C6F90E', isViewed: 'false', activateButton: false},
    {fileName: 'SAMPLE DOCUMENT 2', id: 124234, hash: '9153BB2EFC17BF53218JEFSFH77EDCD3', fileStatus: 
'PENDING APPROVAL', fileId: 'APFEX-9153BB2E-C6KS0E', isViewed: 'false', activateButton: false},
    {fileName: 'SAMPLE DOCUMENT 3', id: 134564, hash: '9153BBMSJFOWN562DW689FWS641WES63', fileStatus: 
'PENDING APPROVAL', fileId: 'APFEX-9153BB2E-CSS9HG', isViewed: 'false', activateButton: false}
  ],     
  
  };
  }

 activatebutton = (key) => {
  const {activateButton} = key
  this.setState({ activateButton: true }, () => {
  }); 

 }

return ( 

 {this.state.file.map(file => (
  <TableRow className={this.state.classes.row} key={file.id} data-id={file.id}>   
    <CustomTableCell align="left" className={classes.row}>
      <a
        id={`download-${file.id}`}
        // onClick={() => downloadFile({ transactionId, fileId, id, fileName })}
        onClick={() => this.activatebutton(file)}
        rel="noreferrer"
        style={{textDecoration:'none',color:'#126ebd',cursor:'pointer'}}
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-script-url
        href="javascript:void(0);"
        
      >
        {file.fileName}
      </a>
    </CustomTableCell>
    <TableRow/>
 )
```

Comment: Define “not working”.

Comment: i want to change the status in the this.state.file[].activebutton from false to true, but it isnot changing

Comment: activatebutton = (key) => {
   let editedFiles = oldFiles.map(file => if(file.id === fileToChange.id){ file.activateButton = true });
this.setState({
file: editedFiles
});


 }

Comment: Hi Kishor, question, where the "oldFiles" came from? is this for the activatebutton function? turns out to be error. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you want to recreate the file array, just changing the `activateButton` property of the clicked item to `true`. To do this in React, you must clone the array, mapping all items to themselves, except the one that you clicked. This one you create from scratch, spreading all the old properties and setting `activateButton` to `true`. Here's the code:

```
activatebutton = (file) => (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevents the link from reloading the page
  const { id } = file;

  this.setState((state) => {
    const list = state.file;
    const newList = list.map((item) =>
      item.id === id ? { ...item, activateButton: true } : item
    );

    return { file: newList };
  });
};
```

Comments:

> activatebutton = (file) => (event) => {

We want `activatebutton` to be a second order function, which receives the clicked item and then the event. Even better would be to pass only the id directly.

> this.setState((state) => { ... })

Whenever you want to update the state based on itself, use the functional setState. Pass a function whose parameter is the current state and the return is an update object. In this case, the `file` property of state.

> item.id === id ? { ...item, activateButton: true } : item

This is short for:

```
if (item.id === id) {
  return Object.assign({}, item, {activateButton: true})
} else {
  return item
}
```

I made a [CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-silence-h65zj?file=/src/App.js) which even includes as the doubleClick event the toggling of the item.

Comment: BTW, why use the <a> tag if you don't want to link to another page? Use a <button> instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: its working!, just that, i removed the (event) & event.preventDefault from the activatebutton function, the page didn't reload as well, this is my expected result, is it ok that i removed those "event"? thanks

Comment: We only add preventDefault when the default behavior is undesired.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {

  // fileName: ['SAMPLE DOCUMENT 1', 'SAMPLE DOCUMENT 2', 'SAMPLE DOCUMENT 3'],
  file: [
    {fileName: 'SAMPLE DOCUMENT 1', id: 123456, hash: '9153BB2EFC17BF53218FA15C977EDCD3', fileStatus: 
'PENDING APPROVAL', fileId: 'APFEX-9153BB2E-C6F90E', isViewed: 'false', activateButton: false},
    {fileName: 'SAMPLE DOCUMENT 2', id: 124234, hash: '9153BB2EFC17BF53218JEFSFH77EDCD3', fileStatus: 
'PENDING APPROVAL', fileId: 'APFEX-9153BB2E-C6KS0E', isViewed: 'false', activateButton: false},
    {fileName: 'SAMPLE DOCUMENT 3', id: 134564, hash: '9153BBMSJFOWN562DW689FWS641WES63', fileStatus: 
'PENDING APPROVAL', fileId: 'APFEX-9153BB2E-CSS9HG', isViewed: 'false', activateButton: false}
  ],     
  
  };
  }

 activatebutton = (key) => {
   let editedFiles = oldFiles.map(file => if(file.id === fileToChange.id){ file.activateButton = true });
this.setState({
file: editedFiles
});


 }

return ( 

 {this.state.file.map(filenter code heree => (
  <TableRow className={this.state.classes.row} key={file.id} data-id={file.id}>   
    <CustomTableCell align="left" className={classes.row}>
      <a
        id={`download-${file.id}`}
        // onClick={() => downloadFile({ transactionId, fileId, id, fileName })}
        onClick={() => this.activatebutton(file)}
        rel="noreferrer"
        style={{textDecoration:'none',color:'#126ebd',cursor:'pointer'}}
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-script-url
        href="javascript:void(0);"
        
      >
        {file.fileName}
      </a>
    </CustomTableCell>
    <TableRow/>
 )
```